# sudo aws s3 sync issues - all folders not synced

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, sudo

I am using the command `sudo aws s3 sync /mnt/ebs-1/ s3://data-backup/TUESDAY`. However only 1 folder within ebs-1 is sync, rest are not syncing.

Folder structure -

```
/mnt/ebs-1/name1/
/mnt/ebs-1/name2/
/mnt/ebs-1/name3/
```

I want to sync the data in s3 as

```
s3://data-backup/TUESDAY/name1/
s3://data-backup/TUESDAY/name2/
s3://data-backup/TUESDAY/name3/
```

Can you help with the command to sync all these folders with single command.

Comment: Are there any files present inside other folders?

Comment: Empty folders won't be synced, since folders don't exist in S3.

Comment: @DeepLF: yes the file structure as below /mnt/ebs-1/name1; /mnt/ebs-1/name2.. etc.

Comment: As Mark said, s3 sync command sync new and existing files, and creates the directory accordingly

Comment: Are there **files** that did not sync? Can you Edit your question to show the listings?